# hours difference not get accurate

Tags: c#

Hi i am converting time to ESt using offset using below function

```
   public static DateTimeOffset ConvertToTheaterTimeZone2(string TheaterTimeZone, DateTimeOffset Date)
        {
            TimeZoneInfo tzi2 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TheaterTimeZone);
            TimeSpan offset2 = tzi2.GetUtcOffset(DateTime.Now);
            Date = Date.UtcDateTime;
            Date = Date.AddMinutes(offset2.TotalMinutes);
            return Date;
        }
```

and then use difference hour calculation using following way but not getting accurate hours plz suggest any other way

```
var hour = (item.Checkindate - ConvertToTheaterTimeZone2("Eastern Standard Time", DateTime.Now)).TotalHours;
```

Comment: you are using `Eastern Standard Time`. We are on `Eastern Daylight Time` now.

Comment: @DanielA.White: That name doesn't mean what it looks like...

Comment: "not getting accurate hours" doesn't describe what you're seeing. Please give a complete example, with your expected results and actual results.

Answer (score 3):

The time zone ID "Eastern Standard Time" doesn't *actually* mean "Eastern Standard Time". It really means "Eastern Time"... From [`TimeZoneInfo.Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The value of the Id property is usually, but not always, identical to that of the StandardName property. The identifier of the Coordinated Universal Time zone is UTC.

So basically, this will give you UTC-5 during winter, and UTC-4 during summer. That's usually what you want... but you *don't* want to perform the conversion in that way. It won't compile (for various reasons) and is overly complciated. You should just use:

```
TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zoneId);
return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, zone);
```

You may also want to consider using my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, which makes a lot of this more fool-proof, as well as allowing you to use the more standard IANA time zone database.

Comment: is "Easter Standard Time" a typo? cause if it isn't, I really wanna move to that place so its always easter

Comment: @KevinL: Yes, I'm sorry to say it's just a typo :(

Answer (score 0):

hello i find out solution by using following i can get actual difference should it proper or not please suggest

public static DateTime ConvertToTheaterTimeZone(string TheaterTimeZone, DateTime Date)
        {
            TimeZoneInfo est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(TheaterTimeZone);
            DateTime targetTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(Date, est);
            return targetTime;
        }

var hour = (item.Checkindate - ConvertToTheaterTimeZone("Eastern Standard Time", DateTime.Now)).TotalHours;